# Force cocoa binding to update after validating (swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I check for and remove spaces from a `NSTextField` in `controlTextDidEndEditing`, but these changes are not reflected in the cocoa bindings (the CoreData entry is not updated). The `NSTextField` is updated, but if you click out of the entry and go back in the spaces come back. **How can I trigger the bound object to update the data store?**

I am bound to .value for the `NSTextField`, I even tried setting .objectValue to .stringValue after the update, but it didn't work.

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(obj: NSNotification) {
    Swift.print("editing is done now")

    let textField:NSTextField = obj.object as! NSTextField

    //if last character is a space remove it.
    while textField.stringValue.characters.last == " "
    {
        Swift.print("last char is a space")
        textField.stringValue.removeAtIndex(textField.stringValue.endIndex.predecessor())

    }

    //save to database now.
    let dele:AppDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    dele.saveAction(nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`textField.stringValue` is not a reference type. You might assign the value back to the text field.

There is a more convenient way to trim strings

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(obj: NSNotification) {
  Swift.print("editing is done now")

  let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
  let string = textField.stringValue
  textField.stringValue = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

  //save to database now.
  let dele:AppDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  dele.saveAction(nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the .stringByTrimming... refinement. Can you clarify what you mean when you say assign the value back to the text field?

Comment: You retrieve the string value from the text field like a copy. When you change the string it actually doesn't change the text field. You need to assign the value back to the `stringValue` property of the text field.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying using a IBOutlet to set the stringValue to after trimming should work, but it doesn't - adding the line         phraseTextField.stringValue = textField.stringValue (where phraseTextField is an IBOutlet to the text field) doesn't change anything. Also - if it is a copy, why does the interface update, but the bound managed object doesn't?

Comment: Have you checked the option `continuously updates value` in the bindings Inspector?

Comment: No - but when I check it I still have the same problem.

Comment: Were you suggesting I directly update the managed object? (I wasn't sure what you meant about .stringValue not being a reference type). Completely ignoring the binding in this case and updating the managed object worked, but it feels like I'm circumventing bindings.         let firstObject = phraseArrayController.selectedObjects.first as? Phrase
        firstObject?.string = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

Comment: In this case I'd recommend to update the managed object directly and drop the bindings.